# Roots of a quadratic equation.

Tags: roots, quadratics

Assume I have an equation

$$a(f(x))^2+bf(x)+c=0.$$
I am required to find the roots of the equation.

When I solve this equation I will obtain a value of $x$, say $p$ and that value of $x$ will give me a value of $f(x)$, say $q$ (i.e. $f(p)=q$). So my doubt is whether $p$ will be called as the root of the equation or is it $q$ that is the root of the equation?

I know my doubt is very silly but please forgive me. I am not that good at math. Thanks a lot for bearing with me and helping me.

Comment: The given equation is function of $x$ or $f(x)$?

Comment: You used $a,b$ twice -- once in the equation and once in labeling the solutions. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry....that isn't intentional.....I will change it right now

Comment: I think what you are asking about is the meaning of the word root: https://www.mathopenref.com/root.html

Comment: Actually I know the meaning of root but I came across a question which has made me wondering something. So I asked this question in order to clarify my doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define a polynomial $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. You need to solve
$$ \tag{1}
p(f(x)) = 0.
$$

To do that, as you correctly note, you first find the roots of $p(x)$, say $p_+$ and $p_-$, so that $p(p_+) = 0 = p(p_-)$, and then solve $f(x) = p_+$ and $f(x) = p_-$, obtaining some solutions, say $x^*$. These final solutions $x^*$ will be solutions of (1) and roots of $p(f(x))$.

---

**UPDATE**

Not sure how a function can be a root of itself. If you mean $p_-$ or $p_+$, then indeed, they are the roots of $p$, so $p(p_+) = p(p_-) = 0$, but they are **not necessarily** the roots of $p(f(x))$.

For example, let $p(x) = x^2-16x+64 = (x-8)^2$ and $f(x) = x^3$. Note that:

- $p(x)$ has roots of $p_- = 8$ and $p_+ = 16$
- $f(x)$ itself only has the root at $0$
- $p(f(x))$ has a root at $f(x) = 8 \iff x = 2$ and $f(x) = 16 \iff x = 2\sqrt[3]{2}$

---

**UPDATE 2**

Let's take another particular case and consider $p(x) = (x-1)^2$ and $f(x) = \tan x$. Then, to solve $$\tag{2} (\tan x - 1)^2 = 0$$ you:

- find all roots of $p(x) = (x-1)^2$, which are $x = 1$
- solve $f(x) = 1$, in other words, $\tan x = 1$, so $x_n = \pi/4 +n\pi$ for any integer $n$.

Thus, roots of (2) are the numbers $(x_n)_{n=-\infty}^\infty$.

Comment: Shouldn't p be the root of p(f(x))? The equation is in terms of f(x) so whatever the value we obtain for f(x) should be the root, right?

Comment: @Priyank please see the update, I hope the example makes it more clear

Comment: Actually I wanted to know if we are given an equation like atan²x+btanx+c=0 then will the values of tanx satisfying the equation be called as its roots or the value of x which on substituting in tanx will satisfy the equation. Like if x=π/4 satisfies the equation then will π/4 be it's root or tanπ/4 ie 1 be called as its root?

Comment: Since the equation is in tanx so the root should be tanπ/4 ie 1...right? Cause then only we will be able to apply properties like sum of he roots=-b/a and product of roots=c/a

Comment: @Priyank see the second update

Answer (score 2):

The equation $a(f(x))^2+ b(f(x))+ c= 0$ is "quadratic" only if f(x) is itself a linear function. If u is a solution to $au^2+ bu+ c= 0$ (there might be two values of u) then any solution to f(x)= u is solution to $a(f(x))^2+ b(f(x))+ c= 0$.  How many that is depends on the function, f.

Comment: So if I say that f(x) is linear then whatever value of x I obtain after equating f(x)=u will be my roots for the equation a(f(x))²+bf(x)+c=0, right?

Answer (score 0):

When you solve the equation, you will get a value for f(x) first. That would be the root: $r=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. Then you would solve $f(x)=r$ for x.

Comment: This means the value of f(x) ie q is the root of the equation...right?

Comment: The simple answer is "yes," but if you have an explicit form for f, say $f(x)=x+1$ and you subsitute that into the original equation, you will get an equation involving x, i.e. $a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)+c=0$ and the root of that equation would be x.

Comment: If I have a trigonometric function like tanx then will the value of tanx be called as the root or the value of x will be the root?

Comment: If you write the equation with f in it then the value of $tan(x)$ would be the root, but if you write it with $tan(X)$ in it then the value of x would be the root. "Root" means the value of the variable for which the result is zero,

Comment: If I have a equation atan²x-btanx+c=0 then the value of x will be the root and not the value of tanx, right? If the values of x satisfying the equation are p and q then will the sum of root be taken as p+q=b/a or rtanp+tanq=b/a

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to obtain a value of $x$ when you solve the equation; you'll obtain a value of $f(x)$, as per the quadratic formula:

$$f(x)=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$